# How to convert a sequence of character to UTF-8 in Java?

Tags: java, unicode

Sorry for asking basic questions here. Pardon me.

I have a sequence a string in this in unicode as follows.

```
String unicode = "\u8BF7\u5728\u6B64\u5904\u8F93\u5165\u4EA7\u54C1\u7F16\u53F7\u6216\u540D\u79F0";
```

How can I convert this to Chinese text or the UTF-8 text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String itself will always be in Unicode; I'm not sure what you mean by "convert this to Chinese text" but to convert it to the binary representation using UTF-8 you'd use:

```
byte[] bytes = unicode.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

or you can use the `Charset` - using the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library for example, you'd just use:

```
byte[] bytes = unicode.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
```

(This gets round the brittleness of specifying a string, and avoids worrying about catching `UnsupportedEncodingException`.)

Or you can declare:

```
final static Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
```

at the top of your class to avoid a whole library as a cure for the string.

Comment: John,

Where did Charsets.UTF_8 come from? It ain't in Java 1.6.

Comment: @bmargulies: It's in Guava (see http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html)

Comment: "请在此处输入产品编号或名称" this is my expected text on the browser for that Unicode input. How can i achieve this?

Comment: @thndrkiss: You need to make sure the encoding you specify in the HTTP response matches what you're actually sending.

Comment: @thndrkiss: if you're using JSP then you usually shouldn't need to worry about the conversion, as long as you specify an encoding that actually supports all the necessary characters (such as UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

You said above you are outputting to the browser?...If you're using a servlet or similar there are various ways of doing it, you may need to be a bit more specific in your question, because you can specify unicode/utf-8/utf-16 in the http response header or in the html output, e.g. outputting the following tags in the inside the `<head>` elements:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`